# Internal error import BACPAC file to windows azure sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, bacpac

I am using MSSQL2014 version CTP2.
Running my databases through Windows Azure SQL Database management.

I've created a BACPAC file via MSSQL of my local database and want to import it to Windows Azure.

1. I create the BACPAC file and upload it to my BLOBSTORAGE container.
2. In Windows Azure click SQL DATABASES
3. Bottom left click New
4. Click IMPORT
5. Choose my BACPAC URL which is the file contained in my BLOBSTORAGE
6. Name the DB and choose the server
7. Click the tick

I then get this error:

> Error encountered during the service operation.   Could not import
>   package.  Internal Error. The database platform service with type
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not
>   valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide
>   the full type name of a valid database platform service.  Internal
>   Error. The database platform service with type
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not
>   valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide
>   the full type name of a valid database platform service.

[image: SQL DB import error]

I can create a new database via Windows Azure which is fine but I'm trying to get my DB up because it has all my data in it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue was that I needed to assign the same DB owner to my db on my local machine as the one that was setup on my azure setup.